# Firebase Web retrieve data

Tags: javascript, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following db structure in firebase

[image]

I'm trying to grab data that belongs to a specific user id (uid). The documentation has the following example:

```
firebase.database().ref('/users/' + userId).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
  var username = snapshot.val().username;
  // ...
});
```

But how can I retrieve data from my example without knowing the unique key for each object?

**Update:**

I tried a new approach by adding the user id as the main key and each child object has it's own unique id.

[image]

Now the challenge is how to get the value of "title".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
firebase.database().ref('/tasks/').orderByChild('uid').equalTo(userUID)
```

Well that is pretty straightforward. Then you can use it like this:

```
return firebase.database().ref('/tasks/').orderByChild('uid').equalTo(userUID).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
  var username = snapshot.val().username;
  // ...
});
```

Of course you need to set userUID.

It is query with some filtering. More on [Retrieve Data - Firebase doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/retrieve-data#sorting_and_filtering_data)

Edit: Solution for new challenge is:

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref('/tasks/' + userUID);
//I am doing a child based listener, but you can use .once('value')...
ref.on('child_added', function(data) {
   //data.key will be like -KPmraap79lz41FpWqLI
   addNewTaskView(data.key, data.val().title);
});

ref.on('child_changed', function(data) {
   updateTaskView(data.key, data.val().title);
});

ref.on('child_removed', function(data) {
   removeTaskView(data.key, data.val().title);
});
```

Note that this is just an example.

Comment: Thank you! Do you think it would it be best practice to add the User ID as the main key for each object? Then try to retrieve each child object.

Comment: I have made an update to my question showing the new structure.

Comment: That depends on use scenario. If you build todo list it would be good to use User ID as main key. I will edit the answer in a while to match your question edit.